# Terraform for_each in for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hello everbody I would like to flatten some data sources that i'm importing but I can't find out how. What I need to achieve is that I have defined list of projects and each project has aad security group. I need to assign to each project email addresses of aad user members of that aad group.

First I have variable object

```
projects_map = {
  project1 = [
    {
      project_name = `Project`
      azure_group  = `AzureGroup`
    }
  ],
}
```

I am already doing some flattening

```
locals {
  projects = flatten([
    for resource in keys(var.projects_map) : [
      for project in var.projects_map[resource] : {
        resource     = resource
        project_name = project.project_name
        azure_group  = project.azure_group
      }
    ]
  ])

  projects__map = {
    for s in local.projects: "${s.resource}" => s
  }
}
```

I am able to get aad members of each project

```
data "azuread_group" "project_group" {
  for_each          = local.projects__map
  display_name      = each.value.azure_group
  security_enabled  = true
}
```

but I cant find how to load aad user email addresses because I need to specify index I want to walk over and I guess there is no way how to walk over all indices.

```
data "azuread_user" "project_managers_users" {
   for_each          = toset(data.azuread_group.project_group[?].members)
   object_id         = each.key
}
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: So both are data sources, right?

Comment: Can you try with `toset(values(data.azuread_group.project_group)[*].members))`?

Comment: yes both are data sources. from azuread_user I can get email.

Comment: data.azuread_group.project_group is object with 1 attribute "project1"
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type list of string.

Comment: Hm, ok, so `values(data.azuread_group.project_group)[*].members` returns a list of strings, can you check that by defining an output and testing locally?

Comment: it returns array of arrays containing member ids (needed for object_id)

users = [
       [
           "xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx",
        ],
    ]

also if i have more projects i get users for each project but somehow they aren't mapped to project (index is missing)

users = [
       [
           "xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
        ],
       [
           "xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
        ],
    ]

Comment: And if you create the output for testing with `concat(values(data.azuread_group.project_group)[*].members)`? Does that look like the data you want?

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code:

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "example_group_members" {
 for_each= data.azuread_group.example_group.members
  group_object_id = data.azuread_group.example_group.object_id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id
}
```

And received same error:

```
“for_each” argument value is unsuitable: the “for_each” argument must be a map, or set of strings ,and you have provided a value of type list of string.
```

[image]

For example, for single project  use below code:

```
data "azuread_group" "example_group" {
  display_name = "test_project_group"
}
locals {
  example_group_members = data.azuread_group.example_group.members
}

Use for_each in the following way:

resource "azuread_group_member" "example_group_members" {
   for_each = { for i , user in local.example_group_members : i => user }
  group_object_id = data.azuread_group.example_group.object_id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id
}


data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for i , user in local.example_group_members : i => user }
  object_id = each.value
}
data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for i , user in local.example_group_members : i => user }
  object_id = each.value
}

output "azureadusername" {
  value = data.azuread_user.user[0].display_name
}



output "azuread_groups_root-users" {
  value = data.azuread_group.example_group.members
}
```

[image]

When using more than one projects :

```
locals {
projects_map = {
  project1 = [
    {
      project_name = "test_project_group"
      azure_group  = "AzureGroup"
    }
  ],
}
}

data "azuread_group" "example_group" {
  for_each          = local.projects_map
  display_name      = each.value.azure_group
  security_enabled  = true
}


data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for i , user in data.azuread_group.example_group[0].members : i => user }
  object_id = each.value
}
```

After getting the users, when tried to create mail for each user it got  triggered with error :

```
UsersClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 400 with OData error: Request_BadRequest: Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already    exists.
```

[image]

Note: The mail property can only be set when one  initially creates the user , but you can update the otherMails property when you want .

Refer : [How to create multiple azure ad users using terraform? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703495/how-to-create-multiple-azure-ad-users-using-terraform)